# Why is ResourceBundle.getBundle(String, Locale) ignoring the Locale?

Tags: java, jsp, multilingual

I have some trouble with adding multi-language to my site.

It works fine on the .jsp file with jstl, but when I try to get the translations with Java code, it ignores the Locale parameter, and uses the Client browsers locale.

I have:

Two properties files:
dictionary.properties, containing: `validate.firstname.empty=You have to enter a first name`
dictionary_nl.properties, containing: `validate.firstname.empty=U heeft geen voornaam ingevuld`

And this Java code:

```
public List<String> validate(UserForm user, Locale locale)
{
    List<String> errors = new ArrayList<>();
    ResourceBundle resources = ResourceBundle.getBundle("dictionary", new Locale("en"));

    if (user.getFirstName() == null || user.getFirstName().trim().isEmpty())
    {
        errors.add(resources.getString("validate.firstname.empty"));
    }
    return errors;
}
```

For testing purposes, I inserted a new instance of Locale to the `getBundle`, but it still returns the dutch translation if my browser is set to dutch, and the English translation if the browser is set to English.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually getBundle() doesn't ignore the Locale, it just ***appears to ignore it*** in your configuration.
Because there is no `dictionary_en.properties` file in your configuration, the Locale for language "en" will have no effect in the ResourceBundle file search.
Test with `new Locale("nl")` instead, and you'll always get the Dutch translation whatever the language set in your browser.
More details in the documentation:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29